# Как правильно сделать кнопку для ссылки на видео на ютубе (это надо как-то генерировать в WP или нужно вручную прописывать)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сделать кнопку (в футере сайта www.01.org.ua) для ссылки на видеоролики на ютубе (это надо как-то генерировать в Wordpress или нужно вручную прописывать)? Где можно найти иконку для этой ссылки?

P.S. Кнопка facebook, которая находится рядом с будущей кнопкой ютуба, сделана таким образом: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов где генерируются кнопки может быть много. Найти где вставляется div с классами contacts и social-icon(возможно в папке с темой footer.php). В конец div дописать:

```
<a href="тут ссылка на видео" target="_blank"><img src="ссылка на логотип ютуба"></a>
```

Если нет в footer.php, то тут все сложней. Если это плагин, то делается в настройках плагина.

Comment: Ваш ответ очень полезный!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно воспользоваться сервисом от youtube.com - по адресу https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button. В опции "Channel Name or ID:" надо удалить надпись "GoogleDevelopers" и ввести ID своего ютуб канала или имя пользователя. Нужно ввести только ID или имя канала без полного адреса по url. После всех настройек будущей кнопки, скопируем для вставки из блока Code (код) сгенерированный нами html-код.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!